# jenkinsfile page load event

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there a way to dynamically load a `dropdown` on page load

```
def loadfolders() {
    checkout scm
    dir("environments/qa") {
        sh "ls -d */ | cut -f1 -d'/' > list_of_files.txt"
        sh 'cat list_of_files.txt'
        liste = readFile 'list_of_files.txt'
        echo "please click on the link here to chose the branch to build"
                   env.BRANCH_SCOPE = input message: 'Please choose the branch to build ', ok: 'Validate!',
                   parameters: [choice(name: 'BRANCH_NAME', choices: "${liste}", description: 'Branch to build?')]         

    }
}
```

The above code works but it works on click event . This code performs checkout, goes to the folder `environments/qa` which has n sub-folders 
which gets populated in a drop-down where the users selects the input from drop-down.

Is it possible to just load the drop-down when I kick start the job ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, with ActiveChoice Plugin.

You may need something like this in your Jenkinsfile:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            name: 'BRANCH_NAME',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            description: 'Branch to build?',
            filterable: false,
            script:
              [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                script:
                  [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: loadfolders()],
                fallbackScript:
                  [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: 'return "master"']
              ]
            ]
```

This allows you to run groovy scripts to populate your choices.

Debugging it is hell, as you need to approve each change to your script, and strange bugs occur, but in the end it works.